# Extjs Jcrop - Crop image with preview

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, jcrop

I try to make preview when i crop a image look like **http://jsfiddle.net/YN7ba/**

[image]

With `region: 'east'` is preview has `width:130` and `height:100`, And `region: 'center'` is origal image

 But when i crop the image preview not correct like

[image]

Here is my code

```
tbar:[{
            text:'Crop',
            handler:function(){
                var me = this;
                $("#myavatar").Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    minSize : [130,100],
                    onSelect:me.getCoords,
                    onChange:me.getCoords
                },function(){
                  // Use the API to get the real image size
                  var bounds = this.getBounds();
                  boundx = bounds[0];
                  boundy = bounds[1];
                });
            },
            getCoords:function(c){      
                if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                xsize = 130,
                ysize = 100;

                var rx = xsize / c.w;
                var ry = ysize / c.h;
                $pimg = $('#preview');
                $pimg.css({
                  width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                  height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                  marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                  marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
              }
            }
}],
```

How to fix that thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you set the height and width of the image in the east region to that of the crop area, you're going to destroy the aspect ratio since the image itself is being constrained to the crop area's square shape.

Comment: @existdissolve i think set width and height is necessary, if i remove that, problem still is the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check your code and find have some issue:

- your Jcrop aspectRatio not match with you minSize and your preview
  size.
- preview image need place into a div element.
- In the getCoords function rx,ry shoud relative with  c.w and c.h

I update your jsfiddle.Please check!

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
 var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'test',
        layout: 'border',
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        tbar:[{
            text:'Crop',
            handler:function(){
                var me = this;
                $("#myavatar").Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    minSize : [130,130],
                    onSelect:me.getCoords,
                    onChange:me.getCoords
                },function(){
                  // Use the API to get the real image size
                  var bounds = this.getBounds();
                  boundx = bounds[0];
                  boundy = bounds[1];
                });
            },
            getCoords:function(c){      
                if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                xsize = 130,
                ysize = 130;
                debugger;    
                var rx = xsize / c.w;
                var ry = ysize / c.h;
                $pimg = $('#preview');
                $pimg.css({
                  width: Math.round(boundx*rx) + 'px',
                  height: Math.round( boundy*ry) + 'px',
                  marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                  marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
              }
            }
        }],
        items: [  
        {
            region: 'east',
            width: 200,
            items : [{
                xtype:'panel',
                width:130,
                height:130,
                items:[{
                    xtype:'image',
                    id : 'preview',
                    src: 'http://www.searchenginepeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Vancouver-Skyline.jpg'
                }]
            }]
        },{
            region: 'center',
            autoScroll: true,
            items: [{
                id:'myavatar',
                xtype:'image',          
                src: 'http://www.searchenginepeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Vancouver-Skyline.jpg'
            }]
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YN7ba/1/)

Answer (score 0):

JCrop seems to have issue when the selection area is not a square. If you change your selection area to square (130x130) and change the code accordingly, it should work.